# Menu not showing up on Android devices

Tags: android, css, ios, mobile, menu

So I’ve been developed a menu where it shows all the buttons on desktop or bigger tablets and just a “menu” button on mobile. The strange thing is that on every android device the button doesn’t show up on portrait but it appears only on landscape. On any other devices (iPhone, iPad, laptops etc) everything is alright. What could be the problem?

That’s the part related to the menu inside of .CSS:

```
nav #menu {
      float: left;
      right: 80px;
      position: fixed;
}

nav #menu li {
      padding-left: 40px;
      display: inline-block;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 80px;
      position: relative;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

nav #menu li span {
      font-weight: 700;
}

nav #menu li a {
      color: #f0d0b5;
}

nav #menu li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
}

#toggle {
      position: absolute;
      right: 30px;
      top: 20px;
      font-weight: 300;
      z-index: 2;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      float: right;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      color: #f0d0b5;
}

.close-btn {
      position: absolute;
      right: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      z-index: 2;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: -2px;
      line-height: 80px;
      color: #f0d0b5;
}

#resize {
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0px;
      position: fixed;
      background: #0f0f0f;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

#resize #menu {
      height: 90px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 45%;
      transform: translateX(-40%);
      text-align: center;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: center;
}

#resize #menu li {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 0;
      font-size: 50px;
      min-height: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#resize li:nth-child(1) {
      margin-top: 140px;
}

#resize #menu li a {
      color: #f0d0b5;
}

#resize #menu li a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
}

#resize.active {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
      #toggle {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            margin-top: 6px;
            margin-right: 4px;
      }

      nav #brand {
            margin-left: 24px;
      }

      #menu a {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 300;
      }

      #resize li span {
            font-weight: bolder;
      }

      nav #menu {
            display: none;
      }
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
      #resize {
            visibility: hidden !important;
      }
}
```

Comment: can you also post your html?

Comment: You can see it in the next comment below.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code regarding this menu:

```
 <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME<span>.</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about" target="_blank">VIDEO<span>.</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">FOTO<span>.</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">BUY<span>.</span></a></li>
                        
                  </ul>

           
                  
                  <div id="toggle">
                        <div class="span">meniu</div>
                  </div> 

            </nav>

            <div id="resize">
                  <div class="close-btn">închide</div>

                  <ul id="menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME<span>.</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about" target="_blank">VIDEO<span>.</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">FOTO<span>.</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">BUY<span>.</span></a></li>
                       
                  </ul>
```